# CMAKE keeps giving error "does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt"

Tags: cmake

I am trying to figure out CMake and can't seem to figure out this basic issue. Every time I try to configure the project using CMake GUI it gives me an error stating the "source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt" when it clearly does. The text of the CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.19.0")

project("Hello_World")

add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" "main.cpp")

install (TARGETS "${PROJECT_NAME}" DESTINATION bin)

install (FILES "main.cpp" DESTINATION src)
```

Also here is an image of my screen with all the relevant info:

[image]

When I navigate to the Hello_World directory in the console and enter cmake, I get this:

```
Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
  cmake [options] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Run 'cmake --help' for more information.
```

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, creating a file with a proper name and extension (in your case, `CMakeLists.txt`) isn't a programming specific task. Of course, anyone (including professionals) could *sometimes* fail with such task. But on Stack Overflow we treat a problems, caused by such fails, are "caused by a typo" ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For those struggling with the same issue see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYmgbqGfv-8
The issue is that you must go into the View settings of the Windows Explorer and make sure that the "file name extensions" box is checked so that Windows won't consider your file extension to be part of the file name. Such as CMakeLists.txt.txt.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you open a console, change to the Hello-World-Directory and call 'cmake'?

Comment: Hey, I updated the post to include that info. Thanks.

Comment: please use console again. create a directory 'build' in the hello-word-dir and run 'cmake ..'

Comment: I just did. I'm getting the same error:  The source directory "C:/Hello_World/Build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: did you call 'cmake ..' (including space and two dots) from the inside the 'build'-dir?

Comment: Yes. Still not working. Here is what I entered: cmake ..-G "Visual Studio 16 2019". I also tried just: cmake ..